# Drag select like in RecyclerView for LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-selector, android-viewgroup, android-touch-event

I would like to implement DragSelect feature in LinearLayout.
For RecyclerView it already exists for example: [here](https://github.com/afollestad/drag-select-recyclerview)

But in `LinearLayout` it gets more complicated. Because onTouch events. The use case would be for day selection. This is a Custom class viewgroup that has this `XML`.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/containerSelectDays"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvCurrentDaysOverall"
        style="@style/TextAppearance.SemiBold"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:text="@string/repeat"
        android:textSize="@dimen/subtitle" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp">

        <views.custom.SelectDayItemView
            android:id="@+id/day1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/day2"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <primoz.com.alarmcontinue.views.custom.SelectDayItemView
            android:id="@+id/day2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/day1"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/day3"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/day1"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/day1" />

        <views.custom.SelectDayItemView
            android:id="@+id/day3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/day1"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/day4"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/day2"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/day1"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" />

        <views.custom.SelectDayItemView
            android:id="@+id/day4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/day1"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/day5"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/day3"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/day1"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" />

        <views.custom.SelectDayItemView
            android:id="@+id/day5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/day1"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/day6"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/day4"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/day1"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" />

        <views.custom.SelectDayItemView
            android:id="@+id/day6"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/day1"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/day7"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/day5"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/day1"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" />

        <views.custom.SelectDayItemView
            android:id="@+id/day7"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/day1"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/day6"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/day1"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I tried inside the custom class with:

```
override fun dispatchTouchEvent(ev: MotionEvent): Boolean {
    val x = ev.x.roundToInt()
    val y = ev.y.roundToInt()
    handleTouch(x, y, ev, day1)
    handleTouch(x, y, ev, day2)
    handleTouch(x, y, ev, day3)
    handleTouch(x, y, ev, day4)
    handleTouch(x, y, ev, day5)
    handleTouch(x, y, ev, day6)
    handleTouch(x, y, ev, day7)
    return true
}

private fun handleTouch(
    x: Int,
    y: Int,
    ev: MotionEvent,
    day: SelectDayItemView
) {
    Log.d("Touched: $x,$y","touch")
    if (x > day.left && x < day.right && y > day.top && y < day.bottom) {
        if (ev.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE) {
            day.changeCheckedState()
        }
    }
}
```

But no success. It sometimes recognizes that the day is touched and sometimes it doesn't so it isn't very reliable. I tried to putting on touch event inside the children, but it only recognizes the first one and doesn't trigger for others. So the `TouchListener` needs to be implemented in the `ViewGroup`.

Comment: Its actually constraintLayout you want this feature on. You can have click listener on all items and then use a controller to select or disselect items on click based on previously selected items.

Comment: Yeah sorry. I should be looking at constraint layout to have this feature on. But click listener won't do. Because I want it to be draggable and clickable at the same time. So you can drag from day 4-7 and you can select just day 3,4,5 etc.